# Generating migrations from Rails schema updates, instead of the other way around

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, schema, migration

I hate writing migrations, but it's important for the schemas to stay in sync. What I'd much rather do is update my `schema.rb` and have Rails notice, then run something which generates the appropriate migration based on the difference between the old version and the current version.

Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Googling revealed this plugin: http://errtheblog.com/posts/65-automatically

It does not actually create migrations for you. But it looks like it does basically what you are looking for.

Edit: Here is the up-to-date link to the plugin code: http://github.com/pjhyett/auto_migrations/